# compare data between 2 table

Tags: sql, oracle, function, plsql

Hey i have a requirement to compare two tables of same structure.

```
Table1
EmpNO - Pkey
EmpName
DeptName
FatherName
IssueDate
ValidDate
```

I need to pass the `EMPNO` as parameter and I need to compare whether any of the column get changes? and return YES OR NO value.

can I able to do that using a PL/SQL Funcation? I was thinking of using the `CONCAT` in-build function to do that.

I'm trying the below one

```
Table1Concat = Select CONCAT(Column1.....6) from tbale1 where emp_no= in_empno;
Table2Concat = Select CONCAT(Column1.....6) from tbale2 where emp_no= in_empno;

IF(Table1Concat<>Table2Concat  ) THEN return data_changed :='YES';
  else data_changed :='NO';
END;
```

Comment: See here: http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:2151582681236 or here: http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:1004115105172

Answer (score 1):

If you only want to detect whether any value is different then ...

```
select count(*)
from (select * from table1 where emp_no = my_emp_no
      union 
      select * from table2 where emp_no = my_emp_no
      )
```

If it returns 1 then the rows are the same, if it returns 2 then there is a difference.

The columns must be in the same order for this to work, or you'll have to list out all the column names in the order in which they match.

If you wanted to do this in bulk for a great many rows then you'd most likely use a different solution, s do not loop through every emp_no running this code for each one.

For bulk data where all emp_id's are present in both tables, use a query of the form:

```
select table1.emp_no,
       case when table1.column1 = table2.column1 and 
                 table2.column2 = table2.column2 and
                 table2.column3 = table2.column3 and
                 ...
            then 'Yes'
            else 'No
       end columns_match
from   table1
join   table2 on table1.emp_no = table2.emp_no
```

You can insert this result directly into a logging table.

Take care of null values though. "any_value = null" is never true, and "any_value != Null" is also never true, so you might need to add logic to take care of cases where one or both values are null.

Comment: Do you need to identify which records are different, which columns in which records are different .. ? Do you need to make sure that one of the tables is update to be the same or include changes from the other?

Comment: basically i have separate table which has just EMPNO and ISDATACHANGED. table1 is the TARGET TABLE; table2 is the current Source Table. so i will compare the TARGET table(tale1) with the Current Source Records(table2) and log the seperate table which says list of EMPNO and whether any column got changed. if atleast anyone of the column gets changed i will Log it as "YES"

Comment: Do you have to detect whether there are additional emp_no's in one table that aren't in the other, or additional rows in both tables?

Comment: Thanks David,  No. im not worried about if the emp_no's are missing.the data entry is bit static. all i need to worry is whether any value get changed to "ANY" "ONE" OF THE COLUMN